# What are the tell-tale signs that my code needs to make use of multi-threading?

Tags: multithreading

I am using a third party API which performs what I would assume are expensive operations in terms of time/resources used (image recognition, etc). What tell-tale signs are there that the code under test should be made to use threads to increase performance?

I have a profiler and will be profiling the code I write which will rely on this API.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have two distinct sequences of events that don't depend on one-another, then consider it. If you have to write bunches of logic just to make sure that two operations aren't getting in each-others way, it pays off by making the two pieces of code clearer.

If on the other hand you find that, in attempting to make something multithreaded, you have to add gobs of code to communicate results between the threads, because one (or both) can't proceed without some information from the other, that's a good sign that you are trying to make threads where they *don't* make sense.

One case where it makes sense to go multi-threaded, even when you have to add communication to do it, is when you have one task that needs to stay available for input, and another to do heavy computing. One thread may poll for input from somewhere, blocking when none is available, so that when input is available it is responded to in a timely manner, and feed jobs to another 'worker' thread, so that processing continues at all times, not just when there's input.

One other thing to consider, is that even when a job is 'embarrassingly parallel' (i.e., requiring little or no communication between the parallelized parts), there are cases where multithreading may not be worthwhile. If your CPU can assign different threads to different cores, multithreading will give you a speed up, by allowing multiple cores to chew through the work simultaneously. But on a single core processor, or even a multi-core one with an unfortunate OS, having multiple threads will not speed things up, as the one core will still have to get through all the work.

Answer (score 1):

Image processing is often cpu-bound. However, if your image-processing api already is designed to leverage multiple cpus, multi-threading probably won't help you. The strategy I usually consider for quickly determining if multi-threading will help is to write a simple program which does the relevant processing over and over again. Then, I will run it on a set of data, then run two instances of the process simultaneously,each on half of the data. There is no need to ensure the data is equalized for such a test; if one process runs out it will just run one instance for anything left.  Timing is done via wall-clock time. I mean this literally; pick a large enough data set that it will take at least a full minute to run, but ideally 5 minutes or longer).

If running two copies at the same time improves throughput significantly, multi-threading is probably a good idea.  Obviously this strategy is only practical in certain instances and in some cases multi-threading can involve leveraging shared output in ways this trick can't emulate. But, it's an absurdly easy test to run, and rarely requires much, if any, code to be written.